# Physical memory usage is too high

Tags: java, ubuntu-14.04, apache-storm

I got this error when I tried to run topology in local mode with storm using

```
mvn compile exec:java -Dexec.classpathScope=compile -Dexec.mainClass=my.Topology
```

the error is

```
ERROR backtype.storm.util - Async loop died!
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Physical memory usage is too high: physicalBytes = 3G > maxPhysicalBytes = 3G
```

How can I solve it? I don't know which Physical memory I should increase ! and if I run the topology in production mode, will this error be disappeared?

> UPDATE

```
Physical Memory Array
Location: System Board Or Motherboard
Use: System Memory
Error Correction Type: None
Maximum Capacity: 32 GB
Error Information Handle: 0x0019
Number Of Devices: 4
```

Comment: Why would `maxPhysicalBytes` be 3G? Are you running a 32-bit JVM?

Comment: excuse me , how can i know if i'm working with 32-bit JVM ? i don't know why maxPhysicalBytes be 3 GB

Comment: Can you provide a full stacktrace?

Comment: i edited the post

Answer (score 7):

I'm also using Apache Storm with JavaCV (OpenCV). I have two Topologies, and the second Topology on the process has two bolts, one for split a video into frames, and another bolt for detecting faces.

I had the same issue:

```
2017-08-02 11:19:18.578 o.a.s.util Thread-5-OpenCVBolt-executor[3 3] [ERROR] 
Async loop died!
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Physical memory usage is too high: physicalBytes = 1G > maxPhysicalBytes = 1G
at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Pointer.deallocator(Pointer.java:562) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
at org.bytedeco.javacpp.helper.opencv_core$AbstractCvMemStorage.create(opencv_core.java:1649) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
at org.bytedeco.javacpp.helper.opencv_core$AbstractCvMemStorage.create(opencv_core.java:1658) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
at OpenCVBolt.detect(OpenCVBolt.java:30) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
at OpenCVBolt.execute(OpenCVBolt.java:104) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
at org.apache.storm.daemon.executor$fn__4973$tuple_action_fn__4975.invoke(executor.clj:727) ~[storm-core-1.0.3.jar:1.0.3]
at org.apache.storm.daemon.executor$mk_task_receiver$fn__4894.invoke(executor.clj:459) ~[storm-core-1.0.3.jar:1.0.3]
at org.apache.storm.disruptor$clojure_handler$reify__4409.onEvent(disruptor.clj:40) ~[storm-core-1.0.3.jar:1.0.3]
at org.apache.storm.utils.DisruptorQueue.consumeBatchToCursor(DisruptorQueue.java:453) ~[storm-core-1.0.3.jar:1.0.3]
```

I was able to solve it. I don't know if you are using JavaCV to work with video and images. If so, and you are working with Maven, make sure you work with JavaCV version 1.3.2 in your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.bytedeco</groupId>
  <artifactId>javacv</artifactId>
  <version>1.3.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Then, you need to apply the following lines in the `prepare()` method in your Bolt to change the property of maxPhysicalBytes.

```
System.setProperty("org.bytedeco.javacpp.maxphysicalbytes", "0"); 
System.setProperty("org.bytedeco.javacpp.maxbytes", "0");
```

That's work for me. The error has disappeared. I hope this helps you.

**UPDATE**

```
@Override
public void prepare(Map conf, TopologyContext context, OutputCollector collector) {

    System.setProperty("org.bytedeco.javacpp.maxphysicalbytes", "0");
    System.setProperty("org.bytedeco.javacpp.maxbytes", "0");

    _collector = collector;
}
```

Comment: really thanks for replying , i don't use JavaCV . I'm dealing with text . Is there another way to try it ? About your error , you solved it by change version of javacv and put some configurations in the bolt . so the problem was not in RAM memory just some changed should be made !

Comment: Regardless of whether you use JavaCV or not, I think the error message will disappear if your Bolt, the prepare () method, is like the one above (I've updated my message).

Answer (score 2):

I can't find a "Physical memory usage is too high" message in the OpenJDK 8 or OpenJDK 9 codebase, so I *suspectt* it is coming from a native code library that is being used by Apache Storm / Spark.

If you could provide a stacktrace that could help track down the "culprit".

The following is not "evidence based" ...

> I don't know which Physical memory i should increase!

It will depend on what the actual cause is.  The possibilities include:

1. Your Java heap is too small.
2. Your JVM cannot expand the heap to the configured max for architectural reasons; e.g. your are running a 32bit JVM and that doesn't provide a large enough address space.
3. The OS has refused to expand your processes memory because it doesn't have enough physical memory or swap space.
4. The OS has refused to expand your processes memory because of a "ulimit" or similar resource restriction.

I would expect different diagnostics for all of the above ... except that it looks like the diagnostic (i.e. the error message) is apparently not coming from the JVM itself.

The above problems could be caused / triggered by:

- Various configurable limits could have been set too small
- Using a 32 bit JVM
- Your machine is physically too small; i.e. get more physical memory!
- Your problem is too large.
- Your application is buggy or leaking memory.

> If i run the topology in production mode, will this error be disappeared?

Impossible to predict.

---

**UPDATE** - Based on the stacktrace, it is clear that the error message comes from the `org.bytedeco.javacpp` library.  Specifically the `Pointer` class.  ([Sourcecode](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp/blob/master/src/main/java/org/bytedeco/javacpp/Pointer.java).)

Looking at the source code, the problem is related to a configurable parameter called "maxPhysicalMemory" which is configured by the "org.bytedeco.javacpp.maxphysicalbytes" system property.

Try changing that property.

You can get more info by Googling for "org.bytedeco.javacpp.maxphysicalbytes"

Comment: thanks for your answer , but i think the problem in the algorithm that i'm using because it needs high memory . so i thought that i'm able to increase the size of Physical which i didn't know if it's RAM or not ? my laptop corei5 with RAM8GB . Can i increase RAM more or i can't ?

Comment: Well the message says that it is only using 3GB ... so that suggests that physical RAM is not the problem.  Can you expand your laptop's memory?  Depends on the hardware.  Check the manufacturer's specifications.

Comment: if you please can you tell me how can i increase it ? I'm on ubuntu 14.04LTS

Comment: what is the difference between laptop's memory and RAM ?

Comment: Expanding RAM on a laptop is not a software problem.  Ask on SuperUser, or somewhere else.  Or do what I suggested - **Check the manufacturer's specifications** - do **they** say what the max RAM is?

Comment: But I think you are ignoring some of the things I said above.  Did you read the **UPDATE** part?  Did you try that?

Comment: i searched but couldn't find how can i changed it ! is there anything i should write it in storm.yaml "configuration file of storm"

Comment: I'm not a storm expert, but you set system properties using a JVM command line option; e.g. `-Dprop=value`.  So look for the place in the YAML where you can set the command line options for the JVM where the exception was happening.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue with my while working on DL4J sentimentRNN, after making much research, I found a resource where I found that I had to add some options to the VM argument

```
-Xms1024m
-Xmx10g
-XX:MaxPermSize=2g
```

I am sure that if you adjust the value of -Xms,-Xmx or XX to your computer spec, you'll find what works for your computer memory.

I had to add this to mine vm option:

```
-Xms5024m -Xmx10g -XX:MaxPermSize=6g
```

I use a somewhat high spec PC and the options above works for me and make my code run faster.

I hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a very similar error while trying to upgrade Java Tensorflow from 1.X to 2.X and while we were also using Java `ZGC` at the same time. So the error looks like this:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Physical memory usage is too high: physicalBytes (12288M) > maxPhysicalBytes (12208M)
    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Pointer.deallocator(Pointer.java:700)
    at org.tensorflow.internal.c_api.AbstractTF_Tensor.allocateTensor(AbstractTF_Tensor.java:91)
    at org.tensorflow.RawTensor.allocate(RawTensor.java:197)
    at org.tensorflow.RawTensor.allocate(RawTensor.java:131)
    at org.tensorflow.Tensor.of(Tensor.java:88)
    at org.tensorflow.Tensor.of(Tensor.java:154)
    at org.tensorflow.types.TString.tensorOfBytes(TString.java:170)
```

This is due to the **JavaCpp** (v1.5.4) (used in the new TF Java artifact v0.3.1) cannot count the physical memory usage correctly when ZGC is used and it counts the memory more than what is really used, then throwing this OOM error [(see info here)](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp/issues/474#issuecomment-832232242). In other situation it might not able to count the memory correctly as well [(see some info here)](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp/issues/468#issuecomment-833161072).

So one of the solution is to set the JVM system property
`-Dorg.bytedeco.javacpp.maxBytes=0` as also described by other answers. Basically it "turns off the physical bytes counting in JavaCPP". Though this may or may not bring other side effect, I am not sure. Or stop using ZGC serves as another solution in my case as we were using it. If ZGC has nothing to do with your situation, then seems the only solution left for you is to set that `maxBytes=0`.

Some other related info can be seen [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/java/issues/315).

Answer (score 0):

This most probably means you are running out of space in the server. If it's a linux box do this to check available memory:-
`ps aux --sort -rss` This sorts the process RAM consumption by the RSS value

> RSS: resident set size, the non-swapped physical memory that a task
>   has used (in kiloBytes).

Example:-

```
zhossain@zhossain-linux1:~$ ps aux --sort -rss
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
zhossain 31934 98.2  8.2 1941088 1328536 pts/4 Rl+  16:13   1:48 python /local/mnt/workspace/
root      2419  0.1  0.5 241156 88100 ?        Sl   Apr05 136:00 splunkd -h 127.0.0.1 -p 8089 restart
root      1544  0.1  0.3 740048 60820 ?        Ssl  Feb15 266:43 /usr/sbin/automount
root      2486  0.0  0.1 331680 28240 ?        S    11:19   0:11 smbd -F
root       867  0.0  0.1 257000 27472 ?        Ssl  Feb15   0:22 rsyslogd
colord    1973  0.0  0.0 304988 13900 ?        Sl   Feb15   1:37 /usr/lib/colord/colord
```

Comment: thanks , but what should i do after this command ? how can i detect the problem and how can i solve it ?

Comment: If you see any process(es) hogging lot of memory find out what that is - try to kill it to free some resource for your operation

Comment: i tried to kill the processes that took much but error still