# Is my memory enough?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, heap-memory

I am running a Java application and received this message:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Cannot allocate new BytePointer(1200): totalBytes = 3G, physicalBytes = 7G
    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.BytePointer.<init>(BytePointer.java:103)
    at org.nd4j.compression.impl.NoOp.compressPointer(NoOp.java:73)
    at org.nd4j.compression.impl.AbstractCompressor.compress(AbstractCompressor.java:131)
    at org.nd4j.compression.impl.AbstractCompressor.compress(AbstractCompressor.java:103)
    at org.nd4j.storage.CompressedRamStorage.store(CompressedRamStorage.java:68)
    at org.deeplearning4j.models.embeddings.loader.WordVectorSerializer.loadStaticModel(WordVectorSerializer.java:2638)
    at com.dl.SentimentClassifier.main(SentimentClassifier.java:76)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Physical memory usage is too high: physicalBytes = 7G > maxPhysicalBytes = 7G
    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Pointer.deallocator(Pointer.java:572)
    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Pointer.init(Pointer.java:121)
    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.BytePointer.allocateArray(Native Method)
    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.BytePointer.<init>(BytePointer.java:95)
```

My Windows laptop has 16G memory and I am setting the Java heap size in Intellij as:

```
-Xms128m
-Xmx10G
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240m
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50
-ea
-Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
-XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow
```

What does the message mean? I am thinking it says the Java application needs 7G memory, and my heap setting is > 7G. If that is the case, why it sends a OutofMemory error?

Comment: Post the full stack trace.

Comment: @shmosel, please see.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44598965/physical-memory-usage-is-too-high

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing up IntelliJ IDEA JVM options and VM options specified for the apps you start from IntelliJ IDEA.

The snipped in your question is the `.vmoptions` file for IntelliJ IDEA and it's applied to the JVM that runs IntelliJ IDEA itself.

Your own apps run in a separate JVM that doesn't inherit the VM options of IntelliJ IDEA JVM.

JVM settings for the app can be adjusted in the corresponding [Run/Debug configuration](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-editing-run-debug-configurations.html), **VM options** field.

[image: vm options]

Comment: So, should I normally set VM through "run configurations", not Intellij's VM configurations? Should I normally set a small VM value for Intellij but a bigger one (if necessary) for runtime configurations? How to coordinate these two values?

Comment: It depends on the size of your project and on the memory requirements of the code you are running. If IntelliJ IDEA complaints on low memory or IDE performance is low, you could try increasing IDE VM options using Help | Edit Custom VM Options. VM options for your app are totally up to you and are set in the Run/Debug configuration. IDE VM options do not affect your application in any way.

Comment: How does IDE complains low memory? also throw an OutofMemory exception? How to distinguish?

Comment: IDE will display a [special dialog about low memory](http://i.imgur.com/1vv02jK.png) and suggest you to increase the `-Xmx` value. Your app will print the OOM in the Run console, so you can't be wrong here.

Comment: Great! One more follow up question, is App VM normally set through "run configuration" options, or through Java code's System properties? I guess it should be directly in code, so that when deploy the code, you don't have to pass a VM parameter to the "java ..." command. Right or wrong?

Comment: Wrong, JVM has to set the memory options before it starts your app, so it can't know it from the code, you must specify the VM options for `java` command, you can't change them later.

Comment: When deploying the apps in production there is usually some launcher script or executable that can read VM options from some file or environment variable and set them for the JVM (like IntelliJ IDEA uses the launcher which reads the options from the `.vmoptions` file).

Answer (score 0):

That means a possible memory leak, and this happens for me mostly because of some native library. In order to debug better, you can do something like following:

1. Monitor memory before running process and then see how its growing along with process execution.
2. See logs and check execution paths, whether there are large memory mapped addresses.
3. Check number of threads whether they bloat up.
4. Consider monitoring the threads stack size.

Answer (score 0):

First of thinking: Why does your app need too much memory? In the normal case, did you run your java app success? In that case, what is the configuration of java option? (Heapsize, GC, ...)

Next, retry with bigger max of heapsize. (16G???)
And another things that you need to check are:
- Current JVM: 32bit or 64bit?
- Physical available memory RAM and swap size are enough to expand?
If it is not problem of env setting, you need to read your library's document carefully.

Finally, I hope this link can help you [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45477973/3471694)