# Why do I have to run 'rebuild project' for every change in Intellij?

Tags: intellij-idea

For any change I made to my class, which contains a main() method, I have to run "Build->rebuild project", to make the changes effective. I am afraid my environment or settings have a problem.

Please help.

Comment: What happens on Build | Build? Enable debug logging and see [build.log](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241085) file. Does it have the line about compiling the modified file on Build action? Are there any errors in build.log or idea.log?

Comment: "Build" is also working, same as "rebuild". My question is why should I run "build"? It should automatically save my change and rebuild automatically? This is Intellij's default behavior.

Comment: Please check that you still have `Build` step in the **Before launch** [setting of the Run/Debug configuration](http://i.imgur.com/QUUGVUh.png). This is the default, but you could have removed it.

Comment: It's also possible to [enable automatic `Build`](http://i.imgur.com/yuu2YZY.png).

Comment: Hey, my "Before launch" box is empty. I added a VM option to my "run configuration", how could that be affected? What else should I put into "Before launch" box besides "Build"?

Comment: By default it's only `Build` for the [Application Run/Debug configuration](http://i.imgur.com/4FtmfW3.png). VM option field has no relation to Before launch and cannot affect it. You could have clicked **—** by accident.

Comment: Also, why isn't "Automatically build project" checked by default in IntelliJ? It should, right?

Comment: No, it shouldn't. By default IntelliJ IDEA doesn't compile the project automatically since it could waste your system resources (or a battery if you are on a laptop on the go). Normally it doesn't make much sense to build before you run the project, so Before launch works fine. Automatic compilation is useful when you make a lot of changes to the big project where compilation of these changes takes significant amount of time and you don't want to wait for the Build when you Run your application or a test.

Comment: Did you managed to solve this issue? I am having the same currently with one project and it takes too much time... @user697911

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Please check that you still have **Build** step in the **Before launch** setting of the Run/Debug configuration. This is the default, but you could have removed it by accidentally clicking on the `—` icon.

[image: Build]

Comment: BTW, is there any difference if I set VM in this "run configuration->VM options", or I set it in "Help->Edit custom VM options"? I want to add more memory to my application.

Comment: Yes, there is difference, I've already [explained it yesterday here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45611565/104891).

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll have to repeat this for every JUnit test case.

To alter the behaviour for all test cases:

1. `Run` -> `Edit Configurations...`
2. In left-hand column, select `Templates` -> `JUnit`

   [image: Select Templates here]
3. Make your changes
4. Hit `OK`

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and I solved it setting the SDK. You need to go in Project Setting and select the Project tab, as show below

Then you can download a JDK or add a new SDK. Finally, you click on OK and run the code.

[image]